# How passing --headless option to chrome from a Java command running Selenium tests with TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, testng

We are running *Selenium* tests from a *Java* command line with *TestNG*.

The one who launch them can select the browser he wants to target: `FIREFOX`, `CHROME`...
For example:

```sh
java -Dbrowser=CHROME -Dtestng.dtd.http=true -Dwdm.chromeDriverVersion=94.0.4606.61 \
-classpath ourTest.jar;ourApplication.jar org.testng.TestNG -testjar ourTest.jar
```

I would like to launch these tests in headless mode (a ability of the *Chrome* browser), sometimes.

I tried :

```sh
java [...] org.testng.TestNG -testjar ourTest.jar --headless
java [...] -DadditionalBrowserArguments=--headless org.testng.TestNG -testjar ourTest.jar
```

and many others names for the `-D` option to pass this `--headless` value.
But my tests are still running with a browser coming in the front...

What is the good parameter to set, to the `--headless` option to *Chrome* through *Java* running *Selenium* by *TestNG*?

Comment: `-DadditionalBrowserArguments` This is a system variable. You should capture this in your code and initialize the browser. Are you doing like that?

Comment: Did you mange to resolve this @Marc?

Comment: Alas, I still have no success yet!